# H Bridge not working

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, h-bridge

I've created an H-bridge for a dc motor that will be controlled by an arduino 
the bridge has one input and a not gate it has two state forward and backward thats the circuit:
[image: H Bridge]

it doesn't work :/ How to create an H bridge with one input ? 
PS: i'm new with transistors forgive me :D

Comment: I can't read that schematic. *Screw this*.

Comment: click on the image

Comment: Not gonna happen.  There is no reason you can't present a readable schematic within the pixels provided here.  That would include trimming the fluff and getting rid of that annoying grid under the schematic.  Don't be so lazy.

Comment: You are missing a base resistor for Q5. But even with that this is a very questionable circuit. Better buy any cheap  H-bridge module from one of the well-known wesbhops.

Comment: @OlinLathrop i don't know where is the problem when i click the picture it becames bigger and i can read it but i will try to re upload it wait

Comment: No Q5 base resistor, and I'd move either R8 or R9 to the other side of the bridge as a pull-down instead. R8/9 value seems very low too. But for a few reasons thats not a great H-bridge to start with.

Comment: @brhans thanks for your answer but what did you mean by R8/9 value is too low ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The circuit should allow the motor to turn forwards and backwards based on a switch.

[image]

Comment: Wait why is my schematic down voted so much? I must have done something wrong... Did I?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it's not recommended to power motors from an Arduino. Probably be better to use 2 power sources.

Comment: This was downvoted because I just gave the OP the answer straightaway instead of guiding him to his own answer, right. (well at the time I made this question, I was new to this site.)